# How can I limit how much a Microsoft account can spend on the Marketplace?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

I'm considering buying Minecraft for the Nintendo Switch for my young son. I want to keep some kind of control over the amount he spends in-game. That could mean disabling in game purchases entirely, or perhaps limiting it to an amount I can "add to the account".

I'm aware of how to do this on the Switch in general, for normal Nintendo games, but as I understand it there are things like Microsoft accounts and an independent marketplace and all kinds of things to get my head around. I've tried reading the documentation and it's confusing and obscure (often seems to be the way with tech companies when it comes to limiting spending, curiously!). Most of the pages refer to other pages, various companies (Microsoft, Mojang, Nintendo), all with various accounts, controls, etc. It sounds like it should be a simple question, but I can't find it directly answered anywhere.

Just knowing if there is a way through the maze for me to achieve this would be great and a couple of signposts, even if no one has the time for a blow-by-blow description of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your best bet would be going through Nintendo's own Parental Control settings!

<sup>*Minor preface; you specified you already know how to set this up for the Switch; this seems to be a popular question, though, so I'm giving the play-by-play per Nintendo's own website anyway.*</sup>

In order to set up restrictions on a Nintendo Network ID for the Switch, you'll need to set up Parental Controls, add your child to your Family Group, and manage them through the proper application available for smartphones ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nintendo.znma&hl=en_US&gl=US&pli=1), [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nintendo-switch-parental-cont/id1190074407)) *or* via your [Account Settings](https://accounts.nintendo.com) on a web browser. To give steps for the website [(Nintendo's direct steps can be found here)](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Nintendo-Switch/How-to-Set-Nintendo-eShop-Restrictions-1406403.html#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20Nintendo%20Account%20for,AND%20the%20official%20Nintendo%20website.);

1. Go to your Account Settings by signing in to your Nintendo Network ID (link above).
2. In the sidebar, select "[Family Group](https://accounts.nintendo.com/#family)".
3. Select your child in the list of members.

   - If your child is *not yet associated*, you'll need to do that by;

     1. Select "Add a member" at the bottom of the list
     2. Select "Create a child account"
     3. Follow the on-screen instructions to create the account, like providing a nickname and their password.
4. Under the section "Parental Controls", select "Spending/purchases on Nintendo Switch eShop and nintendo.com".

From there, simply check the box it requests and save changes. Your child will no longer be able to purchase things from the eShop (this includes Minecraft's Minecoins, which are required to go through the eShop before hitting Microsoft or Mojang at all) without your Parental Controls PIN.

Comment: That's great thank you. It turns out that I already do this through the Ninetndo site. I got an email from Google the other day about some unrelated "Google Family" stuff which was about "alternative payment providers" (or something like that) which warned me that I couldn't control spend through those providers via Google Family. When I saw that Minecraft was by a 3rd-party, not Nintendo and had an eShop, I was worried that the same applied here. I know these two ecosystems are unrelated, but the industry tends to move in one direction en masse (towards your pocket!) Thanks. Very reassuring.